# How to convert clipper program to run it on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: compiler-errors, clipper

I have one Clipper code file say it **ABC.prg** (this program is for console window) with **CMX52.ch** one header file  and I want to make exe for wndows 7 64 bit so i am using HMG3.3.1 compiler for that I made one batch file **trybuild.bat** having content **

> "C:\hmg.3.3.1\HARBOUR\bin\hbmk2 ABC.prg CMX52.CH"

** but when I am running this bat file and compiling this using CMD I am getting the following error.

> Harbour 3.2.0dev (r1407111333) Copyright (c) 1999-2014,
>   http://harbour-project.org/ Compiling 'PACS22.PRG'... Lines 493,
>   Functions/Procedures 7 Generating C source output to
>   'C:\Users\psaxen01\AppData\Local\Temp\hbmk_x7p6wh. dir\PACS22.c'...
>   Done.
>   C:/Users/psaxen01/AppData/Local/Temp/hbmk_x7p6wh.dir/PACS22.o:PACS22.c:(.data+0x
>   2d8): undefined reference to `HB_FUN_COMIX' collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status hbmk2: Error: Running linker. 1 gcc.exe
>   C:/Users/psaxen01/AppData/Local/Temp/hbmk_x7p6wh.dir/PACS22.o
>   C:/Users/p saxen01/AppData/Local/Temp/hbmk_x7p6wh.dir/hbmk_7bm1bk.o
>   -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,- -dynamicbase -mconsole -Wl,--start-group -lhbextern -lhbdebug -lhbvm -lhbrtl -lh blang -lhbcpage -lgtcgi -lgtpca -lgtstd -lgtwin -lgtwvt -lgtgui -lhbrdd -lhbudda ll -lhbusrrdd -lrddntx -lrddcdx -lrddnsx -lrddfpt -lhbrdd -lhbhsx -lhbsix -lhbma cro -lhbcplr -lhbpp -lhbcommon -lhbmainstd -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -ladvapi3 2 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -lwinspool -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -lshell32 -luuid -lole32 -loleaut32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lmapi32 -limm32 -lmsimg32 -lwininet -lhbpcre -lhbzlib   -Wl,--end-group -oPACS22.exe  -LC:/hmg.3.3.1/HARBOUR/lib/win/mingw  hbmk2: Error: Referenced, missing, but unknown function(s): COMIX()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Comix library for Clipper. It's only work with Clipper 5.2.

Your best option is to remove using Comix and use standard RDD functions.